# WordPress 3.x and super admin

Tags: wordpress, admin, super

Is there any way to create a "super admin" above regular admin for non-MU Wordpress installation? I need to have ability to set some limitations for regular admins.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That doesn't really make much sense. Just create a custom role for your sub-admins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, go here http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

WordPress has a function for adding custom roles. The syntax is as follows:

```
<?php add_role($role_name, $role_display_name, $capabilities_array); ?>
```

Then, open up your functions.php and pop this in there:

```
add_role( 'sub_admin', 'Sub Admin', array(
  //add all user capabilities in this associative array
  'edit_posts' => true 
));
```

Comment: Thanks! Also found this to be useful: http://www.shinephp.com/user-role-editor-wordpress-plugin/